# Lock notifications bar Android 8.0

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, android-8.0-oreo, kiosk-mode, android-notification-bar

I´m doing an app like a "Kiosk mode". One part of this proyect consist in lock the notifications bar and this works good in android >= 4.4 until 8.0.

With this code i can lock it:

```
private void disablePullNotificationTouch() {
    WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    localLayoutParams.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
            // Draws over status bar
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
    localLayoutParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.height = (int) (25 * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    localLayoutParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);
    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
}
```

But in Android 8.0 was changed the managment with WindowManager. Actually I can lock ALL the APP CONTENT screen (Not the bar), but i just wanna lock the notify bar:

```
WindowManager manager = ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE));
    WindowManager.LayoutParams localLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                    // Draws over status bar
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
    localLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    localLayoutParams.x=WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    localLayoutParams.y=(int) (25 * getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity);
    customViewGroup view = new customViewGroup(this);
    manager.addView(view, localLayoutParams);
```

What should I change to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: This was disabled to prevent malicious apps from locking entire screen. Now you can pull out the notification bar and kill overlay from there - I've spend a while trying to work around it but haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: Thats a bad notice. Well I'll try to get something similar, thanks.

Comment: Is any other way found?

Comment: @DipendraSharma, I don't know yet.